# How to work with Hibernate Named query and Criteria object together

Tags: hibernate

I defined Hibernate named query,So i am getting this query using criteria.getNamedQuery(),

Here i want to integrate this with criteria object,so that i will put extra constraints.

Any hints please.

Regards,
Raju

Comment: There is no Criteria.getNamedQuery() method. Why use a named query vs just creating your query with the Criteria api?

Comment: @Robby Pond: We dont have direct relation ship with the tables.I have one named query,How to mention like clause in Named query if not possible with criteria and named query combination.Is it possible to do where s.name like :%searchName
%

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't add clauses to a pre-built named query, you can create any query you want with the [SqlQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#querysql-creating) class.

You could also change your named query and add the like clause.

```
session.getNamedQuery("findStuff").setString("likeWhat", value);
```

where your query would be

```
select * from sometable where somevalue like :likeWhat
```

Edit:

You could also do something like

```
Query q = session.getNamedQuery("findStuff");
String query = q.getQueryString(); // the sql statement
query += " and findStuff like :likeWhat"; // add your clause
q = session.createQuery(query);
q.setParameter("likeWhat", value);
```

But I think that's hacky.

Comment: Is it possible to apply like %likewhat%.

Comment: @raj it should implicity do that.

Comment: I have arround 20 search parameters,Based on these parameters i have to build query.Why i choosen named query is we dont direct relationship between the tables.I know with criteria api otherwise.Could you please tell me how to exclude parameters having null values.Becuase of security i wont publish that code in internet.I hope you understand issue.if still want code,i will prepare psuedo.